# Rails gem ckeditor loading custom config.js before it's own config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I've installed the ckeditor gem and everything is working except for my custom toolbar definition. I'm working in the development environment. Checking the inspector in Chrome I see that my custom.js file is being requested BEFORE the ckeditor gem's config and as a result is probably being overwritten. I think I found a crappy solution [here](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/105#issuecomment-5202254), but I was wondering if anyone else has found a better solution.

Here is a sample of my current application.js config:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree ./ckeditor
//= require_directory .
```

I have the config.js file nested in assets-javascripts-ckeditor. I am also using the parameter `:ckeditor => {:uiColor => "#D6A11A", :toolbar => "admin"}` in my cktext_area form method. I know it is being read because the uiColor changes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never really figured this one out. Upgrading to the latest version of ckeditor-rails gem and following all of the installation instructions to the letter has fixed this issue. Also, if you have any custom .js config files used by ckeditor, make sure you add them to your precompile assets paths in application.rb.